# Powershell Get ADGroupMember there is in 2 Identity groups

Tags: powershell

I want 1 list with all users there are member of 2 (both) identity.

I have used this, but it returns first all users in the first identity and then the next identity.

```
$groups = "SMSxxx", "Personalxxxx"
$results = foreach ($group in $groups) {
Get-ADGroupMember $group | select samaccountname, name, @{n='GroupName';e={$group}}, @{n='Description';e={(Get-ADGroup $group -Properties description).description}}
}
$results
$results | Export-csv C:\Temp\GroupMemberShip.txt -NoTypeInformation
```

Best regards,
Peter

Comment: You could use the results you have --> `$results | group-object samaccountname | Where Count -eq 2 | select -Expand Group`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can continue with your current logic and use [Group-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object?view=powershell-7) to find users that exist in all groups.

```
$groups = "SMSxxx", "Personalxxxx"
$results = foreach ($group in $groups) {
    $description = (Get-ADGroup $group -Properties description).description
    Get-ADGroupMember $group | select SamAccountName,Name,@{n='GroupName';e={$group}}, @{n='Description';e={$description}}
}
$results | Group-Object SamAccountName |
    Where Count -eq $groups.Count | Select -Expand Group |
        Export-csv C:\Temp\GroupMemberShip.csv -NoTypeInformation
```